# How do I prevent multiple discordrb bot activations being processed out of sequence?

Tags: ruby, discord

I have a Ruby Discord (discordrb) bot written to manage D&D characters. I notice when multiple players submit the same command, at the same time, the results they each receive are not independent. The request of one player (assigning a weapon to their character) ends up being assigned to other characters who submitted the same request at the same time. I expected each request to be executed separately, in sequence. How do I prevent crossing requests?

```
bot.message(contains:"$Wset") do |event|
    inputStr = event.content; # this should contain "$Wset#" where # is a single digit
    check_user_or_nick(event);  pIndex = nil;  #fetch the value of @user & set pIndex
    (0..(@player.length-1)).each do |y|  #find the @player pIndex within the array using 5 char of @user
        if (@player[y][0].index(@user.slice(0,5)) == 0) then pIndex = y;  end; #finds player Index Value (integer or nil)
    end;
    weaponInt = Integer(inputStr.slice(5,1)) rescue false; #will detect integer or non integer input
    if (pIndex != nil) && (weaponInt != false)  then; 
       if weaponInt < 6 then;
           @player[pIndex][1]=weaponInt;
           say = @player[pIndex][0].to_s + " weapon damage has be set to " + @weapon[(@player[pIndex][1])].to_s;
          else;
              say = "Sorry, $Wset requires this format: $Wset?  where ? is a single number ( 0 to 5 )";         
          end;
    else
       say = "Sorry, $Wset requires this format: $Wset?  where ? is a single number ( 0 to 5 )"; 
    end;
    event.respond say;
end;
```

Comment: By the way, there are a bunch of things here which are non-idiomatic, for example `then; ` can simply be deleted as it has no effect (and more broadly, semicolons are _not needed_ in Ruby). That discussion is for another day, though - I'll just refer you to [rubocop's style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid race conditions in multithreaded code like this, the main thing you want to look for are *side effects*.

Think about the `bot.message(contains:"$Wset") do |event|` block as a *mini program* or a *thread*. Everything in here should be *self contained*  - there should be no way for it to effect any other threads.

Looking through your code initially, what I'm searching for are any *shared variables*. These produce a race condition if they are read/written by multiple threads at the same time.

In this case, there are 2 obvious offenders - `@player` and `@user`. These should be refactored to *local variables* rather than *instance variables*. Define them within the block so they don't affect any other scope, for example:

```
# Note, for this to work, you will have to change
# the method definition to return [player, user]

player, user = check_user_or_nick(event)
```

Sometimes, making side effects from threads is unavoidable (say you wanted to make a counter for how many times the thread was run). To prevent race conditions in these scenarios, a [`Mutex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Mutex.html) is generally the solution but also sometimes a [distributed lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager) if the code is being run on *multiple machines*. However, from the code you've shown, it doesn't look like you need either of these things here.

Comment: Excellent!  I brought the functionality of check_user_or_nick(event)  inside the body of the code as it determines the unique user.   The problem is resolved. Very much appreciated.